# SQL version that doesn't require a database instance to be installed

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, .net, sql-server

I am a `.NET` developer and I am currently coding using `Visual Studio 2013` and `SQL Server 2014 Standard` edition on my work laptop. Company policy says that I may not have a SQL Server instance on my laptop so I have to remove it.

What other versions of SQL can I use that doesn't require a SQL Server instance to run on my work laptop?

Comment: Just a note: if you need the instance in your work and company policy says you can't have it, it's quite a strange company policy.

Comment: If your job requires you to write code that interacts with SQL Server, you need the policy changed.

Comment: Company policy is not what he needs help with. This policy is really not that uncommon.

Comment: They want me to connect to a DEV SQL Server for this. No local instances of SQL Server. I can't always connect to the DEV SQL server because I code at home and I don't always have a decent internet connection.

Comment: Is it a veiled attempt to stop you from working from home? If not, it seems you list out the various items, such as "you expect me to write SQL code at home", etc, including this policy. Point out the contradiction. And then ask them which item *they* are going to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Company policy" is a bit too generic. However, my suggestions are:
 - licensing issue --> go to Sql Express (free)
 - security, listening tcp port on your PC--> take a look at Sql Express LocalDB. https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh510202.aspx

Comment: Company policy means company policy

Comment: What a useful comment.  :(   However, I mean... that in general "company policy" dictates rules and restrictions to protect company assets and data. To drive you to the right direction, it would be useful to know more details about the "policy". Examples: No out-of-standard software on PC?  No service on PC? No database on PC?  No inbound open tcp port on PC? other?

Answer (score 1):

Apologies if I have miss understood your question but instead of running a SQL instance you could use visual studios built in SQL express which would use a local Database attached to the project

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233763.aspx

Or If you are looking for something completely different to MS SQL you could opt to use MySQL.

https://www.mysql.com/why-mysql/windows/visualstudio/

Comment: SQL Server express doesn't have to be installed at all?

Comment: SQL Server express does need to be installed. MySQL requires a server instance of it to run.

Comment: You can still create an edmx database model though without any sql being installed, if your going the entity framework route. You can then generate the database from the model later when your ready to deploy to a SQL instance? I haven't done it this way myself so I may be talking nonsense

Answer (score 0):

There is SQL Server CE (Compact Edition) which is a standalone subset of SQL Server. For non Microsoft, SQLite is a standalone database that does not require a server instance.

Comment: SQL Server CE is **very limited** in what it can do, and it's really a different product than other SQL Server editions. Also, it's being deprecated by Microsoft, so there's not much chance of new versions and improvements for it

Comment: At this moment I am just creating tables, linking tables by foreign key/primary key and creating stored procedures.

Comment: That's true, though it does fit the bill for the requirements given (though not for stored procedures). SQLite is more robust in that respect.

Answer (score 0):

Remote desktop into your home pc or server

Comment: I work for a bank, they won't allow that.

Comment: Sql express won't work then because the sql ports will most likely be blocked. The best answer was already said then. Use visual studio localdatabase and open server explorer.